# SVG in new window gets cut Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, cut

I already asked this, maybe in a too weird way. 
I have a SVG, which is called into a window. 
(you click on a link, window pops up through Javascript and SVG animation shows up)

Works fine in every browser, except FF. The animation itsself does work, but the SVG is like getting cut in the window and only shows like half of it.

Link to website (click on box with blue heads on the left):
[Website with SVG](http://www.pluskat.de/)

Code part:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('<?php bloginfo('template_directory')?>/images/mehrwert.svg', 'newwindow', 'width=1024, height=768'); return false;">Einfach durchklicken</a>
```

I know, width, height 100% ect ect.. Changed it in SVG file itsself didn't work, and i don't know where else to specify it, since I do NOT call up the SVG with `<svg="">`.

Any workaround or solution? Please help!

Thank you.

Comment: check your clip-path attribut on the svg tag. #sozi-clip-path which FF is having problem with. I dnt know what the problem is.

Comment: Which SVG tag you mean? Sorry, I am kind of a noob in this.

Comment: Ahh I found something in the SVG File.  clip-path="url(#sozi-clip-path).. What shall I do with it? Delete?